# How to generate js file based on script content returned by api in .net core

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core

i have two api return script context i need to generate the .js file based on the script content returned by the two interfaces under the wwwroot / js / directory
"~/AbpServiceProxies/GetAll" and "~/AbpScripts/GetScripts" 
[image]

Comment: <script src="~/AbpScripts/GetScript/@(AppTimers.StartupTime.Triks)"></script> where @(AppTimers.StartupTime.Triks) must return some js file name like this "triks.js", tis file must be situated on folder GetScript

Answer (score 0):

In your controller must have some code like this:

```
        public ActionResult SomeAction(Model model)
        {
            if(model!=null )
              ViewBag.JSFileName = "Some.js";
            else
                ViewBag.JSFileName = "AnotherJs.js";
            return View();
        }
```

and after that in SomeAction.cshtml

```
<script src="~/AbpScripts/GetScript/@(ViewBag.JSFileName)"></script>
```

This question can be implemented in many ways.